# What music genre is Tron: Legacy by Daft Punk?

Tags: soundtrack, identify-this-genre, daft-punk

The album is categorized as `soundtrack`. The Band is officially `French-House` style. The album is a mixture of `orchestral` sound with `electro` elements (`hybrid`). There are also electro beats in there. It reminds me of "Stranger Things", "Thor: Ragnarok" and so on. I created something similar (`Hip-Hop` based) and want to publish it on Spotify. Therefore, I need to know: does there exist a special genre name for this style? I googled a lot but without success.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is often not possible to pin down a single genre to an album.

[This review](https://www.allmusic.com/album/tron-legacy-mw0002058895) by Heather Phares identifies electronic and orchestral elements as mentioned by the OP:

> Working with [the London Orchestra](https://www.allmusic.com/artist/the-london-orchestra-mn0000381076), [Bangalter](https://www.allmusic.com/artist/bangalter-mn0000926200) and [de Homem-Christo](https://www.allmusic.com/artist/de-homem-christo-mn0000651498) fuse **electronic and orchestral** motifs seamlessly and strikingly.

The reviewer also notes that

> for most of Tron: Legacy, they're concerned with **pushing boundaries.**

followed by

> It's not until the score's second half that the duo's more typical sound emerges on "Derezzed"'s **filter-disco** and on "End of the Line," where witty 8-bit sounds evoke **'80s video games**.

*(all emphasis mine)*

The infobox on the same site also mentions [Club/Dance](https://www.allmusic.com/style/club-dance-ma0000002544), [Progressive House](https://www.allmusic.com/style/progressive-house-ma0000005002) and [Left-Field House](https://www.allmusic.com/style/left-field-house-ma0000012312) as styles for the album.

When listening to the soundtrack [here](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL10BBAAAFC8626119), the electro-orchestral elements seem to stand out for me, with influences of the House style (as best as I understand it, I haven't heard a lot of music from this genre).

---

Long story short, there is no single genre name to describe this album (or even most music, in general).

Answer (score 1):

At this point they have long abandoned French House and are working more with Electro House. There are typical orchestral elements in the album, as it is common with soundtracks. The more slow and ambient-y that aren't orchestral, are definitely Progressive Electronic in the likes of Vangelis, Klaus Schulze etc.

Tip: it's always a good thing to have a look at RateYourMusic, as genres there are relatively correct and can bring to you a starting point: https://rateyourmusic.com/release/album/daft-punk/tron-legacy-1/